# Model effect of intervention of continuous and cumulative variable

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, model

I have a dependent variable `dv` and an independent variable `iv` in a timeseries dataset.
[image]

The `iv` varies independently from time. Instead, the `dv` varies not only in a cumulative way but is also equal to zero for a long period. I want to estimate the association between the two variables (and other control variables). I wonder if I can leverage the fact that there is a sort of intervention around 1992 even if the introduction of `dv` is progressive.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

This is purely speculative, but you could try modeling your dependent variable (Y) as a function of itself in a first-order auto-correlation type model. Like this:

$$
Y_i = r Y_{i-1} + u_i 
$$

This is a simple regression model where I have used auto-correlation notation (*r* replaces beta, *u* or *disturbances* replaces the residual). So, to calculate your $Y_i$-value, you are using the previous Y-value $Y_{i-1}$ as a function of an estimated parameter, plus the disturbances.

Now you can regress the disturbances onto your independent variable (X):

$$
u_i = X_i + e_i
$$

and in this way, you are explaining the variance in Y that went unexplained by the previous Y-value using X.

I realize as a write this that my first function increases exponentially with increasing Y values, so maybe something like this would be better:
$$
Y_i = r+ Y_{i-1} + u_i 
$$
which just implies that there is an accumulative parameter. Then you can take your disturbances and again regress them onto X, you may include time as a variable too if you wish.

Again, this is highly speculative, this is where I would start, I have no idea where it would end. This problem is very cool though. 
Unless you have a good reason to include the measurements of X before Y begins to increase, I would just start my model where Y becomes greater than 0. I do not have much knowledge of what you are actually studying though.